# Apply regex to a string in irb

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to get this to work. Its driving me nuts.

```
'/leisure/venuename/news'.gsub(/\^(.*)(\/.*)$/, $1#$2)
```

This should return

```
/leisure/venuename#/news
```

so eventualy I can do it to this

```
venue_news_index_path(sensitive_venue).gsub(/\^(.*)(\/.*)$/, $1#$2)
```

Comment: Really?? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25077373/gsub-regex-solution-for-rails-link-to
Why are posting another question?

Comment: Can `'/leisure/venuename/news'` be more than three levels deep? Is it arbitrary and you just need to tweak the last item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This?

```
'/leisure/venuename/news'.gsub(/^(.*)(\/.*)$/, '\1#\2')
```